# Is there a way to detect Flash blockers?

Tags: javascript, flash, plugins

I'm wondering wether there's a Javascript way to detect wether a user has any sort of flash blocking plugin installed so i can accommodate these users properly.

For example, I use 'click to flash', but sites that use SiFR to render text are littered with "click to flash" buttons, which is getting very annoying. I don't use SiFR in my designs for this reason. But if I could spot wether there's a flash blocking plugin installed, I would simply not call the SiFR function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure and don't have the time to dig in more, but have you looked at swfobject ? http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727766/how-to-check-flash-plugin-is-blocked-in-chrome

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717062/how-to-detect-flash-using-swfobject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html. You could call the following after the page has loaded.

```
var movie = window.document.movie;
try {
    //if the movie is blocked then PercentLoaded() should through an exception
    if (movie.PercentLoaded() > 0) {
        //Movie loaded or is loading
    }
}
catch (e) {
    //Movie is blocked
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the page i archived on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20100710000820/http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html

Answer (score 2):

The [`soundmanager2`](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/generated/script/soundmanager2.html) JS library uses the `PercentLoaded` function of a movie reference.
Excerpt:

```
return (flash && 'PercentLoaded' in flash ? flash.PercentLoaded() : null);
```

> Interesting syntax notes… Flash/ExternalInterface (ActiveX/NPAPI) bridge methods are not typeof “function” nor instanceof Function, but are still valid. Additionally, JSLint dislikes (‘PercentLoaded’ in flash)-style syntax and recommends hasOwnProperty(), which does not work in this case. Furthermore, using (flash && flash.PercentLoaded) causes IE to throw “object doesn’t support this property or method”. Thus, ‘in’ syntax must be used.

For getting a reference to a Flash movie, [this page](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashGetObject/) might prove useful.