# how to detect flash using SWFObject

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I have downloaded [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), and included it in my website. Now I want to simply get a `true` or `false` value based on whether or not Flash is installed in the users browser when they visit my site.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think that's what swfobject is for.

Comment: I think that's exactly what SWFObject is for...

Comment: OK, I guess I'm wrong. I was going from the fact that the main use of it is just to embed Flash in a page, given a minimum version. But I guess it has detection features you can access directly as well.

Comment: version detection is automatic with SWFObject. swfobject.embedSWF() function has version control and will display alternate content for a flash player installer if you set it up correctly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.18")) {
  // has Flash
}
else {
  // no Flash
}
```

or replace `"9.0.18"` with the minimum version you require

Answer (score 1):

If You use jQuery SWFObject you could use:

```
if (!$.flash.hasVersion('9')) {
 //has Flash
}
else {
 //no_flash
}
```