# Can I check which Flash plugin is running on my page

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I'm using JavaScript to see if the ShockwaveFlash plugin is on my page as an ActiveXObject. I'm also checking for the application/x-shockwave> I'm using swfobject to load the Flash on to the page.

I can check for which Flash Version I'm running but I'm not sure how to check for which installation of Flash is installed for the browser.

What I want to do is check to see if **Flash for Other Browsers** is installed on the machine.

Is this possible with JavaScript?

#### JavaScript Code

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
    var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
    if(fo) hasFlash = true;
    sendEventToServer("flash_not_found");
} catch(e){
    if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash =         true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect flash using SWFObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717062/how-to-detect-flash-using-swfobject)

Comment: Small distinction: This approach tells you if the plugin is installed in the browser and available to the page, it doesn't answer the question "which Flash plugin is running on my page"? 

The original question implies that 1) you don't know if it's possible to differentiate between brands of Flash players (such as Adobe Flash Player or Chrome's Pepper), AND 2) whether the plugin is actively running on your page. For 1, it might be possible but not reliable. For 2, I don't think it's possible to query the plugin to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are located here but I don't believe it is a W3C standard.

```
var myNavigator = window.navigator ? window.navigator : navigator;
var plugins = myNavigator.plugins
for (var key in plugins) { 
    document.write("<li>"+key+" : "+plugins[key]);
}
```

Looking at the associated objects with for (in) we have an associated array where we have name and version.

```
document.write(navigator.plugins[0].name);
document.write(navigator.plugins[0].version);
document.write(navigator.plugins[0].description);
```

so you need to loop through them. The gobal object to start at is either window.navigator or navigator depending on browser. Your **catch(e){
    if(navigator.** assumes its always navigator, but its not.

Comment: You can check for any and all plugins, flash, pdf, and everything else shows up. but your solution is more specific and uses far less coding hence is a better test and worthy of a plus vote. Going through the navigator object is generic.