# If flash is installed

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject

I'm trying to make simple check if flash is installed like it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041325)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    if (!$.flash.hasVersion('9')) { //error
        //has Flash
        console.log( "flash installed!" );
        ...
```

But I get error, what is wrong here?

> TypeError: $.flash is undefined

Comment: Looks like you need to install the `flash` plugin into `jquery`.

Comment: But.... `flash` in 2017? Seriously? That horse has rightfully been slaughtered _years ago_...

Comment: Further to what @arkascha said - as of Chrome 53, Flash is disabled by default, and I believe Firefox plans to follow suit this year. If your job requires you to use it, fair enough (although I hope to god they have a migration plan), but if this question relates to a personal project, I'd really recommend you avoid using Flash.

Comment: @thinker... why not try the [**accepted Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5717165/2057709) instead? PS: _"Flash is disabled by default"_ is an irrelevant issue since user will be given option to "always enable" by default whenever on a specific site (ie: yours).

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
function flashExists() {
    for (var i in navigator.plugins) {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name && navigator.plugins[i].name.toString().indexOf('Flash') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is returning an error because SWFObject and jQuery are two completely unrelated libraries. SWFObject has no `$.flash` object.

To check if Flash is available using SWFObject, do the following:

```
var meetsMinimumFlashRequirement = swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9");

if(meetsMinimumFlashRequirement){
   //Use Flash
} else {
   //Flash not available, use a fallback
}
```

See LearnSWFObject.com for more details and examples. http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/detecting-flash-player-version-using-swfobject/index.html

I suspect the code you're using is based on a jQuery wrapper for SWFObject. If this is the case, you didn't include the source for the wrapper in your page, therefore the wrapper fails. Personally, I'd just use SWFObject directly.

(Actually, I wouldn't use Flash at all, but if I had to use Flash, I'd use SWFObject directly.)